# Android Camera APIs picture-taken is larger after autoFocus than without autoFocus

Tags: android, api, camera, byte, autofocus

I have tried two different approaches for capturing an image from android camera hardware when User clicks on a capture-picture button. One with calling autoFocus and after the autoFocusCallback completes with a success response, capture the image. Two, capturing the image without calling autoFocus at all. In both cases, I noticed that the resultant byte-array that is passed to the onPictureTaken method has different lengths. The one that comes after autoFocus completes successfully and invokes the autoFocusCallback is usually at least a 50K bytes larger than the one when autoFocus invocation is completely ignored. Why is that so? Could somebody throw some light? What I don't understand is that when autoFocus completes successfully, shouldn't the picture have a good quality? And typically quality is the value of the bits in each of the bytes representing the RGB channels for each pixel. The overall number of pixels, and thereby total number of bytes representing the RGB channels should be the same irrespective of what values of bits are loaded into the RGB bytes. But apparently seems like there are more bytes of data included for a better clarity image after autoFocus is performed than a regular clarity image.

Been researching for over a month now. Would really appreciate a quick answer.

Answer (score 0):

All the image/video capture drivers use the YUV formats for capture. The formats are either YUV420 or YUV422 in most of the cases. Refer to this link for more information on YUV formats http://www.fourcc.org/yuv.php

As mentioned by you the pictures taken after the Auto focus call are much sharper (edges are sharper and better contrast) and the same shapness is missing in images captured without auto focus.

As you know the Jpeg image compression is used to compress the data of the image, the compression is based on Macro blocks (square blocks in image). Image with sharper edges and more details needs more co-efficients to encode than image with blur, since most of the neighbouring pixels looks like they have been averaged out. This is reason why the auto focussed image is bound have more data since it has more details.